# how to write specific column from api to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I use API, got many data but need to write only one to Pandas dataframe and then to csv file
how can i do this? i need currency and rate columns only

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/latest?base=EUR'

get_response = requests.get(url)

print(get_response.content)
```

reponse is

```
b'{\n    "success": true,\n    "timestamp": 1653291723,\n    "base": "EUR",\n    "date": "2022-05-23",\n    "rates": {\n        "AED": 3.891874,\n        "AFN": 96.332724,\n        "ALL": 120.12076,\n        "AMD": 486.326147,\n        "ANG": 1.910798,\n        "AOA": 440.146399,\n        "ARS": 125.559742,\n        "AUD": 1.49136,\n        "AWG": 1.907774,\n        "AZN": 1.796984,\n        "BAM": 1.958501,\n        "BBD": 2.140687,\n        "BDT": 92.747171,\n        "BGN": 1.955884,\n        "BHD": 0.399459,\n        "BIF": 2179.202426,\n        "BMD": 1.05958,\n        "BND": 1.461113,\n        "BOB": 7.300355,\n        "BRL": 5.170217,\n        "BSD": 1.060231,\n        "BTC": 3.4686139e-05,\n        "BTN": 82.245346,\n        "BWP": 12.83561,\n        "BYN": 3.578179,\n        "BYR": 20767.765076,\n        "BZD": 2.137314,\n        "CAD": 1.355568,\n        "CDF": 2124.457448,\n        "CHF": 1.030337,\n        "CLF": 0.032122,\n        "CLP": 886.340415,\n        "CNY": 7.067924,\n        "COP": 4208.651167,\n        "CRC": 711.74061,\n        "CUC": 1.05958,\n        "CUP": 28.078866,\n        "CVE": 110.417129,\n        "CZK": 24.584356,\n        "DJF": 188.746891,\n        "DKK": 7.440804,\n        "DOP": 58.552672,\n        "DZD": 154.438592,\n        "EGP": 19.350685,\n        "ERN": 15.893699,\n        "ETB": 55.044138,\n        "EUR": 1,\n        "FJD": 2.284134,\n        "FKP": 0.867087,\n        "GBP": 0.843796,\n        "GEL": 3.078048,\n        "GGP": 0.867087,\n        "GHS": 8.244159,\n        "GIP": 0.867087,\n        "GMD": 57.376242,\n        "GNF": 9372.913662,\n        "GTQ": 8.136894,\n        "GYD": 221.832492,\n        "HKD": 8.316976,\n        "HNL": 26.044688,\n        "HRK": 7.531387,\n        "HTG": 118.758621,\n        "HUF": 382.210602,\n        "IDR": 15541.387462,\n        "ILS": 3.544575,\n        "IMP": 0.867087,\n        "INR": 82.241939,\n        "IQD": 1547.570278,\n        "IRR": 44820.228002,\n        "ISK": 138.696976,\n        "JEP": 0.867087,\n        "JMD": 163.866665,\n        "JOD": 0.751235,\n        "JPY": 135.279211,\n        "KES": 123.494294,\n        "KGS": 84.628222,\n        "KHR": 4306.032696,\n        "KMF": 494.770756,\n        "KPW": 953.622101,\n        "KRW": 1339.844028,\n        "KWD": 0.324317,\n        "KYD": 0.883605,\n        "KZT": 451.435581,\n        "LAK": 14057.368731,\n        "LBP": 1603.386389,\n        "LKR": 376.408573,\n        "LRD": 161.585115,\n        "LSL": 16.867967,\n        "LTL": 3.128664,\n        "LVL": 0.640929,\n        "LYD": 5.0991,\n        "MAD": 10.616176,\n        "MDL": 20.305389,\n        "MGA": 4285.919145,\n        "MKD": 61.538618,\n        "MMK": 1962.989296,\n        "MNT": 3259.024764,\n        "MOP": 8.570086,\n        "MRO": 378.269824,\n        "MUR": 45.988019,\n        "MVR": 16.344051,\n        "MWK": 866.149081,\n        "MXN": 21.058086,\n        "MYR": 4.645208,\n        "MZN": 67.632728,\n        "NAD": 16.868837,\n        "NGN": 439.852629,\n        "NIO": 37.997351,\n        "NOK": 10.249848,\n        "NPR": 131.573277,\n        "NZD": 1.638153,\n        "OMR": 0.40741,\n        "PAB": 1.060346,\n        "PEN": 3.9603,\n        "PGK": 3.736248,\n        "PHP": 55.384769,\n        "PKR": 213.235927,\n        "PLN": 4.617629,\n        "PYG": 7251.300917,\n        "QAR": 3.857965,\n        "RON": 4.946967,\n        "RSD": 117.499439,\n        "RUB": 62.329807,\n        "RWF": 1088.946708,\n        "SAR": 3.974436,\n        "SBD": 8.607563,\n        "SCR": 14.438411,\n        "SDG": 473.497309,\n        "SEK": 10.486142,\n        "SGD": 1.457722,\n        "SHP": 1.459462,\n        "SLL": 13581.160767,\n        "SOS": 618.272012,\n        "SRD": 22.260709,\n        "STD": 21931.163629,\n        "SVC": 9.277651,\n        "SYP": 2662.141945,\n        "SZL": 16.788471,\n        "THB": 36.311502,\n        "TJS": 13.261298,\n        "TMT": 3.708529,\n        "TND": 3.243904,\n        "TOP": 2.459973,\n        "TRY": 16.843815,\n        "TTD": 7.198816,\n        "TWD": 31.379439,\n        "TZS": 2464.582977,\n        "UAH": 31.322712,\n        "UGX": 3864.924954,\n        "USD": 1.05958,\n        "UYU": 42.945451,\n        "UZS": 11764.462107,\n        "VEF": 226570195087.7927,\n        "VND": 24545.167244,\n        "VUV": 121.073594,\n        "WST": 2.73302,\n        "XAF": 656.781309,\n        "XAG": 0.048294,\n        "XAU": 0.000571,\n        "XCD": 2.863568,\n        "XDR": 0.790993,\n        "XOF": 656.781309,\n        "XPF": 120.315233,\n        "YER": 265.159952,\n        "ZAR": 16.77781,\n        "ZMK": 9537.495082,\n        "ZMW": 18.060768,\n        "ZWL": 341.18428\n    }\n}\n'
```

Comment: Please be aware that you shared your api key in this question. An example of the response would have been enough to understand your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

first load data as DataFrame

```py
import json
df = json.loads(get_response.content)
```

second, choose the rates (currency is index) and save to csv

```py
df[["base","rates"]].to_csv("path/to/csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(get_response.content.decode('utf-8')))[['base', 'rates']]

# for export to csv
# df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

output:

```
    base        rates
AED  EUR     3.893237
AFN  EUR    96.366461
ALL  EUR   120.162829
AMD  EUR   486.496485
ANG  EUR     1.911467
..   ...          ...
YER  EUR   265.252922
ZAR  EUR    16.796411
ZMK  EUR  9540.830787
ZMW  EUR    18.067093
ZWL  EUR   341.303769

[168 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: @irenavox don't forget to `decode` the string as your API returns bytes, I used utf-8 here by default but ensure your have the correct encoding ;)

Comment: just curious, how to treat this timestamp? `"timestamp": 1653291723`

Comment: @NoobVB what do you mean? To get a datetime? You'd need to use `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: close, :) but it spits out a strange timestamp `1970-01-01 00:00:01.653293823`

Comment: @NoobVB depends on what the number means! Here I guess **seconds** (not milliseconds): `pd.to_datetime(1653291723, unit='s')` -> `Timestamp('2022-05-23 07:42:03')`

Comment: how can i find value of any rate of index is string? already googled but this didn't work
print(df.index('AZN'))

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
url = 'https://api.apilayer...'

get_response = requests.get(url)
# Parse the response to a dict
response_dict = get_response.json()
# Turn the rates nodes into a dataframe
data_items = response_dict['rates'].items()
data_list = list(data_items)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns=['currency','rate'])
# Export to csv
df.to_csv('export.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_response = requests.get(url)

# print(get_response.content)

in_json = get_response.json()

# print(in_json)

fd = pd.DataFrame(in_json)

y = fd[['rates']]

print(y)
```

solved but looks not nice and maybe there a more simple solution
i converted to json - then to dataframe - then i will convert to csv